# Why we are using 'special checking for namespace object content:media' here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I came across this python code.

```
def parseXML(xmlfile):

# create element tree object
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

# get root element
root = tree.getroot()

# create empty list for news items
newsitems = []

# iterate news items
for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):

    # empty news dictionary
    news = {}

    # iterate child elements of item
    for child in item:

        # special checking for namespace object content:media    HERE
        if child.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}content': #HERE
            news['media'] = child.attrib['url']                 #HERE
        else:
            news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')

    # append news dictionary to news items list
    newsitems.append(news)

# return news items list
return newsitems
```

Can someone tell me what this *content:media* checking here is? Why are we doing this? I am unable to find something meaning on the internet about what actually this is.

Answer (score 0):

This is SOAP API element. For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
    <m:GetPrice xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
        <m:Item>Apples</m:Item>
    </m:GetPrice>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

In previous XML file, if you want to get `<Item>Apples</Item>`. You have to use:

```
body.find('{https://www.w3schools.com/prices}Item')
```